# Dynamic word wrapping for KDE Plasma terminal emulator (aka Konsole)?

Tags: terminal, kde

I recently migrated from Gnome to KDE. Gnome was my first and only Linux desktop environment. In Gnome terminal dynamic word wrapping was already implemented by default. I don't see that in KDE Plasma. Is there a ready-to-use or easy to implement dynamic word wrapping for KDE Konsole?

Comment: Which konsole version are your running ? AFAIK dynamic word wrapping was implemented in 21.04

Comment: @MC68020 Mine says 20.12.3. `apt update` shows nothing to upgrade... Is something wrong with my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic word wrapping in Konsole has been [requested for ages… (2009)!!](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196998)

[The request was eventually satisfied a dozen of years later](https://invent.kde.org/utilities/konsole/-/merge_requests/321) and released in **Konsole 21.04**

Therefore the only way to get dynamic word wrapping is… to upgrade konsole to >=21.04
Upgrade which will request the upgrade of the kde-frameworks and qt* packages and consequently the upgrade of the whole lot of plasma-desktop & kde-apps packages.

Some versions of some distributions might not, to date, allow that.

Comment: I use Debian without any extra (no Ubuntu or Kubuntu etc) and in Debian database there doesn't seem to be the latest Konsole version..

Comment: @Jackson : Just realizing that too. https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=konsole It seems you'd have to "upgrade" to *bookworm* . Too many things depend on the qt* packages. Making almost nothing of the whole kde framework updateable separatrly.

Comment: I've been trying to open `gnome-terminal` in `/usr/bin/` directory in KDE but when I double-click it, nothing happens. Is there any way to make gnome terminal as the default terminal emulator in KDE?

Comment: @Jackson : You could try via kde-plasma **system-settings > Applications > Default Applications.** In my plasma 5.25.5, this place offers un scrolldown menu for setting default *Terminal emulator*